# Order complexity of a pairing function

Tags: matlab, performance, time-complexity, big-o

I have a code that involves a 2 to 1 pairing of numbers.
The code for this is

```
   function [ A ] = CantorPairing( B )
           [~, b] =(size(B)); 
           %b=sqrt(b);
           k=1;
           A=zeros(1,b/2);
          for i=1:2:(b)
          if( B(i)< B(i+1))
          A(k)= B(i)+(B(i+1))^2;
          else
         A(k)= (B(i))^2+B(i)+B(i+1);
         end
         k=k+1;
         end
```

This is a matlab code that i am implementing.
What this code does is, it pairs the adjacent elements of an array `B` depending on which is greater. So for an `n` size array the number of elements it returns is `n/2`. I have a few questions for this code.

1. Since I am new to computer science, I don't think this is a very efficient code in MATLAB, can I optimize this code.
2. What is the order complexity of this code and it's optimized version?
3. What if I again run this function on the new set `A` to get an array `C` of size `n/4`?

Comment: The natural algorithm of comparing `A[i]` and `B[i]` and then computing `C[i]` is O(n) since computing `C[i]` takes 2 operations (one multiply and one add) and you must do this for every element in `A` and `B`.

Comment: Considering you only show one indexer `i`, you're iterating A and B at the same time right?

Comment: yes i iterate them at the same time. Actually orihinally the vector was of length say 2n. I wanted to pair each adjacent number so i made two vectors from the original one with each position in the new vectors A and B containing elements originally adjacent to each other.

Comment: We need to see more code, particularly the loop that the current snippet implies but does not show. A broad description of *what* the algorithm does is insufficient; big-O complexity analysis can change depending on *how* it does it.

Comment: okay i will put my code in the question

Comment: I have put the code in the question

Comment: Please don’t double-post: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/210468/151754 — It’s rude to the people that help you. Maybe I make an effort to answer your question, but it has already been answered elsewhere, and you don’t care for my answer any more?

Comment: Okay i will delete it from there, and yes this should not be done but just out of frustration i did it. Actually i am not able to delete thw question from there.